# How to track a long hold for a finger in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, events, touch

How could I track an event like touch on iPhone screen for 2 seconds. Like in Safari to save image for image added to a UIWebView?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create an NSTimer with `+scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:` in your view's `-touchesBegan:withEvent:` method, and cancel it (using `-invalidate`) in `-touchesEnded:withEvent:`. If the method its selector points at gets called, then the user held their finger on the view for whatever duration you set the timer's interval to. Example:

Interface (.h):

```
@interface MyView : UIView
    ...
    NSTimer *holdTimer;
@end
```

Implementation (.m):

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)evt
{
    [holdTimer invalidate];
    holdTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(touchWasHeld) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)evt
{
    [holdTimer invalidate];
    holdTimer = nil;
}

- (void)touchWasHeld
{
    holdTimer = nil;
    // do your "held" behavior here
}
```

Comment: That is what I do in a game. Works well.